# Why does smallhog.c show less than 100% CPU usage on my system?

Tags: linux-kernel, cpu-usage

> [[Documentation/cpu-load.txt](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.1/Documentation/cpu-load.txt)] includes an example program, `smallhog.c`.  According to the linked thread on LKML.org it was able to hog the CPU, and the kernel only reported a few % CPU usage or less.
>
> I tried compiling and running it on my current system.  The kernel reported the program's CPU usage as about 80%.  So the situation appears to have changed a bit.

Source: [Documentation/cpu-load.txt says Linux cpu load *could* be misleading. Are there new (or old) mitigations that it does not mention?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/527416/documentation-cpu-load-txt-says-linux-cpu-load-could-be-misleading-are-there)

But smallhog.c still has *some* effect.   According to "task-clock" in `perf stat`, it *really* uses about 100% cpu time.  But the normal CPU accounting in `top` thinks it only uses 80% cpu time.  The same is true of  "user"+"sys" in `perf stat`.

Why does my specific system not report 100% CPU usage for `smallhog.c`?

My kernel version is 5.1.15-300.fc30.x86_64.

Linux says my TSC is stable.

```
$ sudo perf stat ./smallhog
^C./smallhog: Interrupt

 Performance counter stats for './smallhog':

         10,072.25 msec task-clock                #    1.000 CPUs utilized          
               235      context-switches          #    0.023 K/sec                  
                65      cpu-migrations            #    0.006 K/sec                  
                44      page-faults               #    0.004 K/sec                  
    28,736,276,128      cycles                    #    2.853 GHz                       75.00%)
    18,394,555,284      instructions              #    0.64  insn per cycle           (74.99%)
     3,530,232,530      branches                  #  350.491 M/sec                    (75.01%)
        58,545,233      branch-misses             #    1.66% of all branches          (75.01%)

      10.076806251 seconds time elapsed

       3.481505000 seconds user
       4.458544000 seconds sys
```

```
$ sudo journalctl -k |grep -iE "tsc|sched_clock"
Jul 09 10:58:25 localhost kernel: tsc: Fast TSC calibration using PIT
Jul 09 10:58:25 localhost kernel: tsc: Detected 2294.623 MHz processor
Jul 09 10:58:25 localhost kernel: clocksource: tsc-early: mask: 0xffffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x21135dc5295, max_idle_ns: 440795305870 ns
Jul 09 10:58:25 localhost kernel: TSC deadline timer enabled
Jul 09 10:58:25 localhost kernel: clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc-early
Jul 09 10:58:25 localhost kernel: sched_clock: Marking stable (1353126208, 521414)->(1368149024, -14501402)
Jul 09 10:58:25 localhost kernel: tsc: Refined TSC clocksource calibration: 2294.689 MHz
Jul 09 10:58:25 localhost kernel: clocksource: tsc: mask: 0xffffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x21139c00f92, max_idle_ns: 440795293667 ns
Jul 09 10:58:25 localhost kernel: clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc
```

```
$ lscpu
...
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               61
Model name:          Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5300U CPU @ 2.30GHz
Stepping:            4
CPU MHz:             1189.926
CPU max MHz:         2900.0000
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the other 20% of CPU time is accounted to interrupts :-D.

Run `smallhog` on a specific CPU, using `taskset -c 0 ./smallhog`.  Inside `top`, press the <kbd>1</kbd> key.  Here is the result:

`%Cpu0  : 22.6 us, 56.1 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa, 21.3 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st`

`hi` means "hardware interrupt".